# Using java in the vanilla universe with Condor

Tags: java, condor

I have a job in a condor cluster that is composed of two parts, a python script, as well as a Java file. I would like to run the python script and have it call the jar file, and run only on machines where Java is installed. Is there any way to do this? Many of the machines in the cluster do not have Java installed, and thus I get an error when I run the script. Basically I would like to add a requirement to my job that lets it run in the vanilla universe on machines where there is a executable named "java".

Comment: Couldn't you just check for the presence of the `java` executable?

Comment: That's exactly what I would like to do actually, I just can't figure out how to do it right now.

Comment: If you're already running shell commands maybe just run `which java`?

Comment: I would like to specify that as part of my condor job file rather than as a shell command, so that the job is not assigned in the first place to a machine that does not have java.

Answer (score 0):

it really seems like you should run it in the Java universe with

```
Requirements= (HasPython)
```

or, I would think you could run it in the vanilla universe with something like

```
Requirements= (HasJava && HasPython)
```

You should be able to accomplish what you want just with the ClassAd itself. I run a job that runs java code and python code and I run it in the java universe so I don't have to worry if the worker has java or not - I know it will. All my workers have python so I don't do a python check.